# When to drop support for deprecations in git-flow / semantic versioning

Tags: workflow, git-flow, release-management, semantic-versioning

We work by the [git-flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) workflow and we stick to [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/). Today we discussed how to handle deprecations. Two questions have arisen:

### A. Semver: Is it ok to gracefully deprecate a feature in a minor release (e.g. v1.12.0)?

"Gracefully" means: The feature is still supported but a warning is shown in development environment. Support will be removed with a major release (in case of v1.12.0 with v2.0.0 or a subsequent major release).

### B. Git-flow: How do you properly drop support of a deprecated feature?

Given we want to drop support for a feature in v3.0.0 while the last 2.x-release is v2.14.0. So 2.14.0 *must* support the feature while 3.0.0 *must drop support* for the feature, as any feature supported in 3.0.0 cannot be dropped before 4.0.0.

Subsequently we must remove the feature in the `release/3.0.0` branch. But according to git-flow, a release-branch should only accept bug fixes.

Any advice highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** One way to achieve this is to simply remove the feature on `develop` after the last 2.X `release` branch is made. Or feature flag the removal, and disable it on the first 3.X `release` branch. If you can't do either of those for some reason, it's still OK to do it on `release`.

**Details:**

Usually you can treat dropping this feature the same way you would treat adding a new big feature by simply merging it into `develop`. The only difference is that you need to make sure you get the timing right such that you don't complete the code removing the feature into `develop` until the last 2.X `release` branch is created. The next `release` branch that comes off of `develop` will have the code and will be the 3.X release. If the issue is that you don't know for certain when the last 2.X release will be, you could either wait until you do know and then merge the removal code into `develop`, or, consider feature flagging the removal with a config change. Then your change on the `release` branch whenever you create the 3.X version would simply be toggling the config.

That being said, perhaps ultimately it doesn't matter anyway:

> But according to git-flow, a release-branch should only accept bug fixes.

Note there is no such thing as a Git Flow Authority which dictates what you *must* do. There is a popular *standard* [Git Flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), but here I use the word "standard" to just mean "original" version that many companies use as a *guideline*. It is not "the" standard, as no such standard exists. I think the particular text you're referring to [regarding release branches](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/#creating-a-release-branch) (emphasis mine):

> This new branch may exist there for a while, until the release may be rolled out definitely. During that time, bug fixes may be applied in this branch (rather than on the `develop` branch). **Adding large new features here is strictly prohibited.** They must be merged into `develop`, and therefore, wait for the next big release.

Note even "strictly prohibited" is a (strongly) suggested best practice. There are no Git Flow Gods that will strike you down if you ever violate this rule. Besides, in your case, it could be easily argued that removing a deprecated feature on the `release` branch is not considered "adding a large new feature". (Even if we ignore the distinction between add/remove and new/old, perhaps the feature being removed is not "large".) Regardless, sometimes new large features *do* get added to a `release` branch, for a variety of reasons. This may violate best practices, but in the real world it's not always possible to follow best practice 100% of the time. Think of Git Flow as a guideline to work in, when it makes sense to do so. Note that Vincent Driessen specifically points out in the Note of Reflection that he didn't intend for Git Flow to become "dogma or panacea".

Comment: Thanks @TTT for your wonderful advice. It not only answers my question, but also provides the context needed to make confident decisions. And hej … you even put a smile on my face while reading (No Git Flow Gods? Really?)!

Comment: @rekomat Hehe. My snark about the Git gods wasn't directed at you, but more generally at how many people seem to treat Git Flow as dogma, as the author pointed out. It's even more evident in the context of people saying, "I don't like Git Flow because you must do X, and therefore I do Y." But Git Flow doesn't even prohibit Y. When you start digging into various Git branching strategies that people created because they don't like Git Flow, you may find how similar they are but with different names.